# How to combine two servlets response without having any direct connection between them (Just like between two servlet there is a payment gateway )

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Just like between two servlet there is a payment gateway ,  servlet1 response goes to servlet2 and from servlet2 it redirected to servlet3 I need to combine the response of servlet1 and servlet3 for generating output.

Its somthing like we are using a payment gateway between two servlet and generating response by combining both servlet response, Please help

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Just store relevant data in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question. For payments, you usually create a token/reference and store that in a DB on the first request/session. Later, after the user pays, the payment gateway will do a HTTP POST to your service, and one of the parameters will be that token/reference. Now you just need to validate the id/token and mark whatever you need as paid.

Try to avoid storing data in the session for any payment related data, as the node where the payment is taking place might go down for any reason while the client is paying... and you don't want him/her complaining that the money is gone, but he didn't get the product/service.

### Edit

You have a few options about how to notify the customer. The more traditional answer is (and this works fine for low volumes of transactions):

- Customer starts a payment, so the server creates and stores a transaction reference.
- Customer is sent to the PSP site.
- The customer completes the payment on the device.
- The device finds out the payment is 'complete' and starts polling the server with the payment reference.
- (time passes)
- server receives the async notification from the PSP with the outcome of the transaction (and the payment reference). The server updates the transaction on the DB.
- (the device is still polling)... pools once more and finds the outcome of it.
- Job done

There are a few more advanced techniques, like async requests, but I would say to not use them unless you are already using them somewhere else in your application OR you have a considerable volume of transactions.

Comment: But I Want To ask How I can generate the receipt for the customer on his mobile phone because the data comming is in asynchronous form.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the response of servlet1 to the session and get it in session2

Servlet1:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("sessionResponse", object);
```

Servlet2:

```
Object value = request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionResponse");
```

Comment: Hmm, ServletContainers can serialize the session when load is balanced among different servers. Are you sure that the response and all its attributes are serializable? And what would be the sense of storing in session a response that would have already be commited meaning data sent to client???